Backspace key not working while using Ajaxtoolkit masked edit extender and validator (ASP.NET, Microsoft Edge, Ajaxtoolkit)
I have 2 textboxes using ajaxtoolkit's masked edit extender and validator to input dates using a calendar extender as well as to ensure that dates are entered in the proper format for the db. For some reason within both textboxes you cannot backspace or delete, you can only overwrite, similar to the insert function on a keyboard.
Currently I haven't seen much on this issue except for some really old posts on GitHub that don't have responses, I'm using Microsoft Edge with this ASP.NET project if you are trying to recreate the problem.
I'm currently on Ajax toolkit version 1.0.20229, as this is not my own site but for the business I work for so I cannot update it.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDt" runat="server" width="100" placeholder="00/00/0000" />
      <asp:ImageButton ID="StDateButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" />  
      <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator8" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender8"
      ControlToValidate="tbStartDt" Display="Dynamic" InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid"
      ToolTip="Input a Date">
      </ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator>
      <asp:Label ID="FrDateLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
      <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender8" runat="server" Mask="99/99/9999"
        MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="tbStartDt">
      </ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
      <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender8" runat="server" CssClass="MyCalendar"
        PopupButtonID="" TargetControlID="tbStartDt">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
      <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender10" runat="server" CssClass="MyCalendar"
        PopupButtonID="StDateButton" TargetControlID="tbStartDt">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>


What version of the AJ toolkit are you using? Remember, older versions pre-date HTML5 standards, so I would strong suggest you update the AJ toolkit to the latest version, as that probably will fix this issue. However, you don't show your extender, and you don't show your input masks being used. And you don't mention what version of the AJ toolkit you are using. So, versions older then 10+ years often have some bits and parts that don't play nice with HTML5 standards. Also the newer versions of the AJ toolkit do NOT require the AJ script manager, but you to now use the standard asp.net one.

Please don't paste your code as an image. Here I am with a 10 minute coffee break, and I would have taken your markup and pasted it into a test page, and would have verified if the newer AJ toolkit works.  As it stands now, I only be able to look at htis say later today, or if lucky, sometime tomorrow. This is a great reason why posting a image of code is of little use, since then you expecting me to re-type all that markup, perhaps clean your room, and do your dishes for you? The easer you make your code to test and try then the easier it becomes for this community help you out.

As for making this work? Well, as noted, I have no idea if using the newer AJ toolkit will work, but given your version looks to be 1.0, that looks to be 15+ years old. And using such old code and expecting it to work with all of the newer HTML5 compliant  browsers? If upgrading is off the table, then you need to place a warning on the site that you have to use 15 year old Edge browsers and ensue that people are say running windows 7, or some such. It not going to be a practical approach to use some version of the AJ toolkit written before HTML5 standards came out for browsers.

Thank you kindly for posting some markup, as I was able to test + try your markup with the later version of the AJ toolkit. See my response below.

Ok, now that I can try/test the markup with the newer version of the AjaxToolkit?
When I paste in your sample markup, then the backspace does work fine.
However, that is sure quite a bit of markup for a simple date picker.
I mean, you can drop in a standard textbox, and set the textmode = "Date".
So, with this markup:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDt" runat="server" 
            TextMode="Date"/>

The above will output a correct HTML5 compatible date picker. So, no mask required, no date extender is required either.
The date format will ALSO of course respect the client side (user's browser settings), since as a general rule the end user should set and pick and choose THEIR own regional settings on THEIR computer - not you attempting to force some date format that is 100% different then what your users have and use every day.
The result of the above simple markup is this:

Note close in above:
No icon was specified - it is automatic placed for you.
No date formatting was specified - again automatic and based on the user's regional settings - not you the developer.
No JavaScript, and no additional masking is required, it just works, and requires a rather limited amount of markup. In fact, you only have to drop in the text box, and then set TextMode="Date".
I should also point out that there is also a time picker, and it will show an "watch/time" icon if you set TextMode="Time".
So, all in all, a super simple amount of markup without requiring a mask, nor an extender, and does not require the AJ toolkit at all.
As a FYI, pasting in your existing markup (and using latest version of the AJ toolkit) then the masking etc. works, and the backspace works, however the default date did seem to "disappear" when I clicked into the text box (I'm sure with some tweaking it would work fine).
However, I would consider using a standard text box, and setting TextMode="Date", as that produces a rather nice date picker, and one with the least amount of markup, code and efforts. In other words, I would consider giving the built in date picker a try by a simple setting of TextMode="Date" for the text box, and see how well that works.
